# Combined fields in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the best way to solve the problem?  User inputs and edits string "tom had a dog".  I'd like the model and database to store "tom" and "had a dog" as separate fields.  I recall solving this problem when dealing with telephone number strings but can't quite recall how I did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a setter in your model that isn't mapped to a database field... this setter would contain the logic that determines how the string is split in two, then sets the two fields accordingly:

```
class MyModel

  def mysetter=(string)
      # your logic to split up the string
      field1 = ...
      field2 = ...
  end
end
```